# Get navigation is not functioning properly

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx, dart-null-safety

[image]I tried building flutter project with sound null safety and I am using get: ^4.6.1. Previously, without enabling null safety, navigation using Get was working fine, but now, navigation is not functioning properly. Initially, I got error
**Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4028 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.**
which was resolved by using addPostFrameCallback. However, Whenever I try to navigate to new screen by tapping "See All", print statement gets executed, but it won't navigate to new screen unless I tap or drag somewhere else in screen.

```
GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("tapped");
                      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
                          (_) => Get.toNamed(AllProductsScreen.route));
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      "See All",
                      style: kHeaderTextStyle,
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: I tried using get:^4.5.1 as well, but issue still exists

Comment: finally resolved, the issue was never with navigation, this issue was due to using async function without await statement in main function. No need to use addPostFrameCallback.